# Do we put a comma before "then" when it's the last word in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Do we put a comma before "then" when it's the last word in a sentence?

If she goes, I'm not going, then.

Comment: Your example is non-idiomatic in the first place. The standard form would be *"If she goes then I'm not going"*. Most people wouldn't put a comma before "then", but it would really depend on whether you intended to indicate a pause in the spoken form, rather than on any specific grammatical rule.

Comment: In your specific example, the presence of the comma determines the meaning. "If she goes, I'm not going, then." -> If she goes, I'm not going *at all*. "If she goes, I'm not going then." -> If she goes, I'm not going *at the same time, but I might go at a different time*. But I agree with @FumbleFingers, it's a poor construction to begin with.

Comment: @Roger: Your point is very relevant. To my ear, putting "then" at the end is so bad it's a bit pointless wondering whether to include a comma or not. But in my suggested rephrasing, putting a comma ***after*** "then" would strongly imply the *at that time* sense. As opposed to the *in that case* sense, which would probably be the default reading with no punctuation or additional context.

Answer (score 6):

There are examples where you should use it, and others where you shouldn't.

> Is she going? I'm not going, then.

In this case, "*I'm not going, then*" is equivalent to "*Then I'm not going*". If you change this example to a single conditional statement ("*If she's going, then I'm not going*"), then — as the comments indicate — you would not transpose 'then' to put it at the end of the sentence.

> Q. Shall we meet at eight o'clock?
>   A. Sure, let's meet then.

In this case, "*then*" is a reference to the phrase "*at eight o'clock*" used by the person asking the question.

Comment: Does this sort of comma have a name or identifier?  i.e. "the oxford comma" or "those weird commas you use instead of parenthesis"

Comment: I could not tell you the technical name — but parenthetical as the word might be, you should never put "then" in parentheses in any context like what I describe above.

Comment: Guh... I've been trying to figure out what this little guy is called forever.  I can't even figure out how to phrase my Google searches ("comma before last word also, then" doesn't seem to cut it).